# R: Split dataframe into columns and recombine to rows

Tags: r

Trying my very best for several hours now and hope someone can help me with the following.

The dataset I load into R looks like this (with many many more replications)

[image]

My output should look like that:

[image]

`split.default(Mydata, rep(1:3, each = 5))`
did the job in splitting the data frame into columns but I then do not know how to a) add the Replication column and b) how to combine the different tibbles into a single dataframe.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Data:

```
structure(list(Replication1 = c("Timestamp", "44046", "44046.02884259259", 
"44046.065949074073", "44046.088472222225", "44046.0934837963", 
"44046.105208333334", "44046.115613425929", "44046.35355324074", 
"44046.419537037036", "44046", "44046.02884259259", "44046.065949074073", 
"44046.088472222225", "44046.0934837963", "44046.105208333334", 
"44046.115613425929", "44046.35355324074", "44046.419537037036", 
"44049.058587962965", "44049.08630787037", "44049.184525462966", 
"44049.188009259262", "44049.28429398148", "44049.373472222222", 
"44049.464212962965", "44049.472627314812"), ...2 = c("a", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), 
    ...3 = c("b", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...4 = c("c", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "37", "37", "37", "37", "37", "37", "37", "37"), 
    ...5 = c("d", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "20", "20", 
    "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20"), Replication2 = c("Timestamp", 
    "44046", "44046.02884259259", "44046.065949074073", "44046.088472222225", 
    "44046.0934837963", "44046.105208333334", "44046.115613425929", 
    "44046.35355324074", "44046.419537037036", "44049.058587962965", 
    "44049.08630787037", "44049.184525462966", "44049.188009259262", 
    "44049.28429398148", "44049.373472222222", "44049.464212962965", 
    "44049.472627314812", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    ...7 = c("a", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), ...8 = c("b", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...9 = c("c", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "37", "37", "37", "37", 
    "37", "37", "37", "37", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), ...10 = c("d", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Replication3 = c("Timestamp", 
    "44094.918553240743", "44094.960196759261", "44094.960393518515", 
    "44095.006030092591", "44095.259652777779", "44095.275034722225", 
    "44095.31045138889", "44095.323263888888", "44095.386574074073", 
    "44095.425659722219", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...12 = c("a", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...13 = c("b", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...14 = c("c", 
    "37", "37", "37", "37", "37", "37", "37", "37", "37", "37", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), ...15 = c("d", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", 
    "20", "20", "20", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you please use `dput(Mydata)` and paste the output as code in your question in order to help you?

Comment: Added the data! Apologies and thank you for the hint to dput()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this brute force approach with a loop. We can detect the position of key variables to determine a start/end path and then use the loop to format the data. Finally, we bind the results using `do.call()` and `rbind()`:

```
#Code
index <- which(grepl('Replication',names(Mydata)))
index2 <- index[-1]
index2 <- index2-1
index2 <- c(index2,dim(Mydata)[2])
#List
List <- list()
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(index))
{
  df <- Mydata[,(index[i]:index2[i])]
  val <- names(df)[1]
  colnames(df) <- df[1,]
  df <- df[-1,]
  df$Replicate <- val
  List[[i]] <- df
}
#Bind
mdf <- do.call(rbind,List)
```

Output:

```
mdf
# A tibble: 78 x 6
   Timestamp          a     b     c     d     Replicate   
   <chr>              <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>       
 1 44046              0     0     0     0     Replication1
 2 44046.02884259259  0     0     0     0     Replication1
 3 44046.065949074073 0     0     0     0     Replication1
 4 44046.088472222225 0     0     0     0     Replication1
 5 44046.0934837963   0     0     0     0     Replication1
 6 44046.105208333334 0     0     0     0     Replication1
 7 44046.115613425929 0     0     0     0     Replication1
 8 44046.35355324074  0     0     0     0     Replication1
 9 44046.419537037036 0     0     0     0     Replication1
10 44046              0     0     0     0     Replication1
# ... with 68 more rows
```

Comment: That's brilliant. It works for the data I uploaded. If I apply the code to a much larger dataset (85 Replications) I get an error after the loop: Error in df[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions - Do you have an idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Do a fast check typing index and index2 on console and see if there is some issue like overlaps. Also check if the length of both vectors is the same. Use names to see if replications are continuous!

Comment: No I got the Error in index[i]:index2[i] : NA/NaN argument error message. Let me put another data example

Comment: Sorry cannot put another data example. But what would I need to change if there are more replications and more variations in their lengths... ?

Comment: It is strange, try to keep the same structure as the data you shared, also I saw you upvoted a question no helpful for your issue. Should you upvote/accept this answer? You can add another sample of data editing the question and removing the previous dput

Answer (score 3):

Without a sample of the data (using dput not posting an image) I give some directions:

1. save in txt file many files as many table replications you have
2. load in R each dataframe with the read.csv statement. For each step apply the replication value by using the `cbind` statement

   rep1_df <- read.csv('replication1.txt')
   rep1_df <- cbind(rep1_df, 'replication1')
3. create a resulting dataset with the `rbind` statement:

   compound_df <- rbind(rep1_df, rep2_df, etc...)

Below a working example.

Here's a couple of simplified input data file:

**rep1.txt**

```
Timestamp;a;b;c;d
03/08/2020 00:00;0;0;0;0
04/08/2020 01:00;0;2;0;0
```

**rep2.txt**

```
Timestamp;a;b;c;d
03/09/2020 07:00;1;0;0;0
05/09/2020 14:00;1;7;40;0
```

And here the code to use:

```
rep1_df <- read.csv(file='rep1.txt', sep = ';')
rep2_df <- read.csv(file='rep1.txt', sep = ';')

rep1_df <- cbind(rep1_df, Replication = 'Replication1')
rep2_df <- cbind(rep2_df, Replication = 'Replication2')

compound_df <- rbind(rep1_df, rep2_df)

         Timestamp a b c d  Replication
1 03/08/2020 00:00 0 0 0 0 Replication1
2 04/08/2020 01:00 0 2 0 0 Replication1
3 03/08/2020 00:00 0 0 0 0 Replication2
4 04/08/2020 01:00 0 2 0 0 Replication2
```

Comment: Thanks @alessio ! I have added the dput version now!